# ActionListener Preventing Program for Running?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Alright I have two questions here.

1. I had my program UI working before I added the `help.addActionListener(this)` into my program. I was having some issues with static methods because Eclipse wanted a main method somewhere in there, and the `ActionListener` didn't like being in a static method. (I was doing the method call in the `public static void main(String args[])` at the time.) Once I moved the method call to a constructor or a separate method, the program will not execute anything in the code.

```
 JFrame screen; 
 JButton start, submit, help;
 JPanel UI,userWhite, passWhite;
 JLabel usrTxt, passTxt;
 JTextArea usrInput, passInput;

static String[] strings = new String[2]; //See getInformation() method
HELP runner = new HELP();

public UserInterface()
{
    run(); 
}

public void run()
{
    uiSetup();
    displaySetup();
    inputSetup();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    // Had to make every method static if I did the method call in here
    // which was fine until it came time to use "help.addActionListener(this)".
    // When I did use this method in a static context, I kept getting an error. 
}


public void uiSetup()
{
    // This method sets up the initial interface which all other
    // elements within this program will be built off of

    screen = new JFrame("Bing Rewards Bot v.Development 1.0");
    screen.setVisible(true);
    screen.setSize(800, 600);
    screen.setResizable(false);
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    UI = new JPanel();
    UI.setVisible(true);
    UI.setLayout(null);
    UI.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    screen.add(UI);
                                        // Buttons must me initialized here. If done in another method,
                                        // it can sometimes block JPanels from appearing. Fixed: 12/27/15
    start = new JButton("Start Bot");
    start.setVisible(true);
    start.setFocusable(false);
    start.setBounds(300,300,200,75);
    UI.add(start);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.setVisible(true);
    submit.setFocusable(false);
    submit.setBounds(75,170,100,50);
    UI.add(submit);

    help = new JButton("HELP");
    help.setVisible(true);
    help.setFocusable(false);
    help.setBounds(355,500,100,50);
    help.setActionCommand("helpClicked");
    help.addActionListener(this);
    UI.add(help); 
}


public void displaySetup()
{
    // This method sets up the interface text

    usrTxt = new JLabel("Bing/Microsoft Account Username");
    usrTxt.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16));
    usrTxt.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    usrTxt.setBounds(0,0,310,20); // Adjusts Absolute Size
    usrTxt.setLocation(25,50); // Sets Location
    UI.add(usrTxt);

    passTxt = new JLabel("Password");
    passTxt.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 16));
    passTxt.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    passTxt.setBounds(0,0,310,20);
    passTxt.setLocation(25,100);
    UI.add(passTxt);
}

public void inputSetup()
{
    // This method handles the User name and Password field setup

    //----- Adds White Space In JTextAreas ----------------------------
    userWhite = new JPanel();
    userWhite.setVisible(true);
    userWhite.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    userWhite.setLocation(25,70);
    userWhite.setSize(200,25);
    UI.add(userWhite);

    passWhite = new JPanel();
    passWhite.setVisible(true);
    passWhite.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    passWhite.setLocation(25,120);
    passWhite.setSize(200,25);
    UI.add(passWhite);

    //----------- JTextAreas ------------------------------------------
    usrInput = new JTextArea();
    usrInput.setBounds(0,0,200,18);
    usrInput.setLocation(25,75);
    usrInput.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    usrInput.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    UI.add(usrInput);

    passInput = new JTextArea();
    passInput.setBounds(0,0,200,18);
    passInput.setLocation(25,125);
    passInput.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    passInput.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    UI.add(passInput);
}

public void getInformation()
{
    // This method gets the information from the
    // JTextAreas in the inputSetup method and
    // stores it into an array called "strings"
    // ("strings" is initialized in the class)

    strings[0] = usrInput.getText();
    strings[1] = passInput.getText();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("helpClicked")) 
    {
        UI.setVisible(false);
        runner.helpSetup(screen);

    }
} 

}
```

When the button is clicked, the plan is to have the `JPanel` "UI": `UI.setVisible(false)`, and then create an `Object` to a different class, where there will be a different `JPanel` to `setVisible(true)`, and then add that to the `JFrame` "screen". How would I get the method call to execute while still getting the button to work?

2. Does anyone know of any tutorials for taking user inputed information and then sending that to a website, and then taking data from a website to display it inside a java program? I've looked around on here and other places, but its either to much of what I'm looking for, or not enough.

Comment: You second part is request for tutorial.

Comment: First and foremost, the best way to swap Swing views is to use the tool built just for this: a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  As for your current problems, you will need to tell us more: exactly what is or isn't happening? Are you seeing error messages? Is your code throwing an exception? Consider posting a [mcve] that we can run and test.

Comment: Your code won't run because your main method is **empty** so of course you're seeing nothing. Go to a basic tutorial or the first chapter of any Java book as you'll need to learn basic Java before doing any GUI's. Even learning Hello World type programs will help here.

Comment: The problem is in you class `HELP` It's clearly doing some long running task on the Swing Thread.

Comment: Put at least this in your main method: `UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();         userInterface.uiSetup();` This creates an instance of the UserInterface class and then calls the uiSetup() method on it. But this boils down to understanding what a class is, what an instance is and how to start instances. This must be fully understood before trying anything more complex such as creating GUI's, and any good tutorial or textbook will show you what you need to know.

Comment: @WalterM: it's worse than that -- he's not running anything because his main method is empty.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main method should be used to create and set up the main objects that run your code, here your UserInterface object. Since your main method is empty, your program runs, but nothing is displayed since the JVM is never told to create or display any GUI. So for you, you'd need to create your UserInterface, and then call its uiSetup method so that it displays the GUI:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();
    userInterface.uiSetup();
}
```

or something similar.

To swap views, use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) (please check the link for the tutorial), which is a layout built specifically for changing views.

Other issues:

- Avoid null layouts and `setBounds(...)`. While this seems like the easiest way to create GUI's, it isn't and it becomes a maintenance nightmare if you ever need to change components around or add new components to GUI's -- an often occurrence. Instead use the layout managers.

For example your code could look something like:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyUserInterface extends JPanel {
    public static final String MAIN = "main";
    public static final String HELP = "help";
    private MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(this);
    private HelpPanel helpPanel = new HelpPanel();

    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

    public MyUserInterface() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(mainPanel, MAIN);
        add(helpPanel, HELP);

    }

    public void showview(String key) {
        cardLayout.show(this, key);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyUserInterface");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyUserInterface());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

class HelpPanel extends JPanel {
    public HelpPanel() {
        add(new JLabel("Help", SwingConstants.CENTER));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Help Panel"));
    }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = Color.CYAN;
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    private MyUserInterface myUserInterface;

    public MainPanel(MyUserInterface myUserInterface) {
        setBackground(BG);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Main Panel"));
        this.myUserInterface = myUserInterface;
        add(new JButton(new HelpAction("Help")));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class HelpAction extends AbstractAction {
        public HelpAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            myUserInterface.showview(MyUserInterface.HELP);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you previously started your program form another class since java will always start the `main` method. So currently nothing happens because your main method is empty. If you would do something like this

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();
}
```

it should start the program. But if you are starting the program in another class you can safely remove the `main` method and just tell eclipse to run the other classes main method.

To solve the error with the `ActionListener` you have to either implement the interface `ActionListener` like

```
public class UserInterface implements ActionListener {
    //Your code...

    //The ActionListeners method
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("helpClicked"))
        {
            UI.setVisible(false);
            runner.helpSetup(screen);

        }
    }
}
```

or you could also use a anonymous implementation of `ActionListener` like this in your constructor:

```
help.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        UserInterface.this.UI.setVisible(false);
        UserInterface.this.runner.helpSetup(screen);
    }
});
```